# Select box is generated by JavaScript but value is not passed on form submit

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms, http-headers

I've got a second select box which is created using Javascript when the user selects a value from the first select box. The JS runs a PHP file which queries a MYSQL database for the relevent items depending on the first selection.

The problem I'm having is that the value for the item the user selects in the second box is not passed in the header when the form is submitted.

Does anyone have any ideas how to get the value and pass it in the header?

Thanks.

This is the PHP for the second select box:

```
<?php
$cxn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "db") or die("Couldn't       connect");
$choice = $_GET['choice'];
$query = "SELECT ID, Model FROM models WHERE MakeID ='$choice'";
$result = mysqli_query($cxn, $query) or die("Couldn't execute query");

echo "
<select id='model' name='model'>
<option value='0'>Model (any)</option>";
while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
echo "
<option value='$row->ID'>$row->Model</option> \n

    ";
}
echo "
 </select>  ";
?>
```

Comment: How about showing us the relevant code so we can see what you are doing.

Comment: Without seeing (and taking your word for) it being inserted in to the form correctly, I don't think you're going to get much of an answer. Maybe show some of the HTML and what you have? Otherwise, this is another "my form doesn't work, what do you suggest".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After creating select field you must append it to your form.

```
<script>document.getElementById("MyForm").appendChild("select_field_id");</script>
```

Comment: Hi Elvin85. Thanks for your answer. Do I put that bit of script on the page or echo it out with the select field?

Comment: You can put it after </select>.  echo "</select>  <script> ... </script>"

Comment: I've put it after the closing select tag, but nothing is happening. The php code is where it is placed, after the </select> tag at the bottom. Have you got any idea?

Comment: Yo do these things with AJAX yeah? then you must have javascript function on first select ONCHANGE(). You must put document.getElementById("MyForm").appendChild("select_field_id"); code to the end of that JS function. If you don't understand, or you don't use AJAX, then please put here your first file code which contains first select field.